# Ender 3 S1 Pro extruding/jamming on random layers

Tags: underextrusion, ender3

My relatively new Ender 3 S1 Pro with default extruder started to under extrude and jam on some layers. When it happens I can hear extruder skipping/clicking noises. I printed same g-code multiple times and happened on different layers.

I replaced the nozzle *(default 0.4)* with the new one *(same size/type, [from Ender's 24Pcs Brass Mk8 pack](https://www.creality3dofficial.eu/products/24pcs-brass-mk8-nozzle-print-head-for-cr-10-ender-series))*, but got similar results.

I removed and checked the nozzle and throat, but didn't see anything abnormal, there was no filament between the nozzle and the throat.

I tried using different SD cards, tried different extruder temperatures.

I'm running default latest firmware from Ender. I haven't performed any PID tunes or any other firmware changes, I've just changed the nozzles and adjusted screw/belt/roller tensions.

The models were sliced on Cura v5.3.0 on Mac and Windows versions *(default Ender S1 Pro profile)*.

I don't think it's a filament or slicer issue as my Tronxy CRUX1 printed same model with the same filament just fine.

**What could be the main causes for such jams/under extrusion?**

Under extrusion example:
[image: Under extrusion example]

Nozzle and throat:
[image]
[image]